# How can I use the Gesture detector within a Framelayout to initiate left and right animations on the cardview it is part of?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I am using this framelayout to hold each of my textviews etc. and I would like, if possible when my gesturedetector detects either a left or right swipe to initiate the appropriate left or right animations on that particular cardview.

But I can't find any information online for how to accomplish this.

Code:

**MyFrameLayout:**

```
public class MyFrameLayout extends FrameLayout implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;
    private UserTaskListActivity userTaskListActivity;

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 20;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;

    public MyFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public MyFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public MyFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialize(context);
    }

    private void initialize(Context context) {
        if(context instanceof UserTaskListActivity)
            userTaskListActivity = (UserTaskListActivity) context;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                           float velocityY) {
        if(userTaskListActivity == null)
            return false;
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                leftSwipe();
                return true;
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                rightSwipe();
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;   }


    private void rightSwipe() {
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Swipe to the right",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void leftSwipe() {
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Swipe to the left",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
        LogUtilities.verbose("onLongPress: " + event.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
                            float distanceY) {
        LogUtilities.verbose("onScroll: " + e1.toString() + e2.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent event) {
        LogUtilities.verbose("onShowPress: " + event.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
        LogUtilities.verbose("onSingleTapUp: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/taskViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <com.example.testing.android.layout.MyFrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           ......

        </com.example.testing.android.layout.MyFrameLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not wrong you are trying to implement the swipe behavior to your frame layout. I have tried and made some changes in your class. Hope this will help you .....

```
public class MyFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

private static final int mWidth = 500;

public MyFrameLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialize(context);
}

public MyFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize(context);
}

public MyFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initialize(context);
}

private void initialize(Context context) {
    setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
}

private float mDisplacementX;
// private float mLastMoveX;
private float mDisplacementY;
private float mInitialTx;
private boolean mTracking;

private OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            mDisplacementX = event.getRawX();
            mDisplacementY = event.getRawY();

            mInitialTx = getTranslationX();

            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // get the delta distance in X and Y direction
            float deltaX = event.getRawX() - mDisplacementX;
            float deltaY = event.getRawY() - mDisplacementY;
            // updatePressedState(false);

            // set the touch and cancel event
            if ((Math.abs(deltaX) > ViewConfiguration.get(getContext())
                    .getScaledTouchSlop() * 2 && Math.abs(deltaY) < Math
                    .abs(deltaX) / 2)
                    || mTracking) {

                mTracking = true;

                if (getTranslationX() <= mWidth / 2
                        && getTranslationX() >= -(mWidth / 2)) {

                    setTranslationX(mInitialTx + deltaX);
                    return true;
                }
            }

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            if (mTracking) {
                mTracking = false;
                float currentTranslateX = getTranslationX();

                if (currentTranslateX > mWidth / 4) {
                    rightSwipe();
                } else if (currentTranslateX < -(mWidth / 4)) {
                    leftSwipe();
                }

                // comment this line if you don't want your frame layout to
                // take its original position after releasing the touch
                setTranslationX(0);
                return true;
            } else {
                // handle click event
                setTranslationX(0);
            }
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

private void rightSwipe() {
    Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Swipe to the right",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  // write code to remove the data from source and notify change to adapter
  // if you want to change remove the item on swipe.
}

private void leftSwipe() {
    Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Swipe to the left",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   // write code to remove the data from source and notify change to adapter
   // if you want to change remove the item on swipe.
}
```

}

Comment: That moves what is within the card on swipe, not the actual card. What would you suggest to fix this?

Comment: your MyFrameLayout class will extend the android.support.v7.widget.CardView in place of FrameLayout and in Xml replace android.support.v7.widget.CardView with custom class name and also replace com.example.testing.android.layout.MyFrameLayout with framlayout. Hope it will work ....